# Adding a custom dynamic block to checkout

Tags: cart, layout, blocks

I need to add 2 custom blocks, one on the cart page (below the totals) and one on the checkout complete page. I've searched the net and can find no information on how I can do this. These blocks will contain custom js and need to interact with a custom model. I know how to write the modules required but I'm stuck with the XML and where I should place the templates/layout.

Can someone please give me a very short example (the equivalent of a 'hello world' that displays a block on the cart page)?

Answer (score 2):

I think it will help you:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>new.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/template" name="new" as="new"  template="new.phtml" after="checkout.cart.totals" />
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Just put this short code into your custom layout XML.

Answer (score 2):

Better idea define `a new layout  file` from you  custom module `config.xml`  file .

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <custommodule>
                <file>custommodule.xml</file>
            </custommodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then you need put this `custommodule.xml` file at `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTemplate/layout/`

Now,you can add your `template file (.phtml) using` Page handler

We know that checkout  cart page handler is `checkout_cart_index` and checkout success page is `checkout_onepage_success`.

on custommodule.xml.you need put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<checkout_cart_index>
   <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="Giveaname" as="GiveAliasename"  template="YourPathlocation"  />
    </reference>        
</checkout_cart_index>

<checkout_onepage_success>
   <reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="Giveaname" as="GiveAliasename"  template="YourPathlocationofTempkay"  />
    </reference>        
</checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

The `advantage of custom layout file` is if module disable then the template is not works.

Comment: Thank you @Amit that looks like what I was looking for. I'll give it a try this morning and let you know how it went.